# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PRE_CLIENT_CREATE

Tags: java, cxf-client

We've upgraded to use the Apache CXF 3.0.0-milestone2 and have we are using the WSDL2Java to generatea WS Client. However, when calling the client, we get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PRE_CLIENT_CREATE
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:493)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:350)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

I checked that I don't have any old libraries lying around and as far as I can see it is only the CXF 3/3.0.4 libraries present.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this was because I had mixed versions of the apache CXF. I have a cxf-bundle I was pulling which had a milestone version in it which I didn't realize is no longer supported when version 3.0.4 was released. 
AFter pulling in the cxf-core 3.0.4, this is now fine